# Adding table records with type Date manually

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, date

I'm using Visual Studio connected to my SQL Server to create a new database and populate a table with some mock data for application development testing. I created a table with 5 fields, an auto-increment PK, three nvarchar(50) fields and a date. When I view the table data and attempt to add a row, it doesn't allow me to type into the Date field nor give me any way to insert a date into the field. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How are you trying to input the date? You should be able to insert it like `'yyyy-dd-mm'`

Comment: I right click the table in the Object Explorer, click View Data and start inputting data into the fields that are text. The field that is of type Date is grayed out and it doesn't allow any typing. I Imagine I can easily write some SQL Insert commands to do it but to just quickly change data it would be nice to have the ability to edit fields on the fly like I see others do when they aren't using a Date field. I really don't want to make it an nvarchar that just holds a date.

Comment: What are you inputting for date? Like if you were to put today's date, would you do `'2020-01-10'`?

Comment: I'd suggest writing your own insert script. It'll save you headaches

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was not descriptive enough and it turns out it was a confusion between a timestamp and a datetime datatype. I was trying to use timestamp thinking when I did an insert it would give the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. As it turns out the timestamp is really rowversion and has nothing to do with an actual datetime. I have since changed the datatype to datetime and have had no problems.